# Python alternative to _winreg

Tags: java, python, jython

I am accessing a python script using jython and apparently the _winreg module is not supported. Are there any alternatives to this module? I am using jython 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to access the Windows registry [via Java instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).