# Accessing winreg from jython

Tags: python, jython, winreg

Why can't access the `_winreg` module from `jython`?

```
c:\>python  
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
import _winreg  

c:\>jython  
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_31
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
import _winreg  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_winreg`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) is not available in Jython.

In CPython on Windows, `_winreg` is a built-in module (mirroring the underlying Windows API) that is compiled into the Python interpreter. This can be verified by checking the [`sys.builtin_module_names`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) property.

See also [Python alternative to _winreg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522650/python-alternative-to-winreg).